# Redux TypeScript can not map state to props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I follow redux tutorial in JavaScript but I can not map state to props when I write with TypeScript.

**App.tsx**:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Todo from '../models/Todo';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Main from './Main';

export interface State {
  todoList: Todo[];
  filterStatus: string;
  isAdding: boolean;
}

const defaultState: State = {
  todoList: [],
  filterStatus: 'SHOW_ALL',
  isAdding: false,
};

const reducer = (state: State = defaultState, action: {}) => {
  return state;
};

const store = createStore(reducer);

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Main />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Main.tsx**:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { State } from './App';

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>{this.props.filterStatus}</div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state: State) {
  return {
    filterStatus: state.filterStatus,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Main);
```

it says:

> [ts] Property 'filterStatus' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{
>   children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{}>'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the typings for props for the component.

```
export interface MainProps {
  filterStatus: string;
}

class Main extends React.Component<MainProps>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. It's correct. Btw, how about my State interface, is it correct or I need to refractor?

Comment: Looks okay to me for now